# Is "Were there cattle on the road?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, collective-nouns

Is

> **Were** there cattle on the road?

grammatically correct? What is the rule regarding the usage of *was* and *were* around collective nouns ?

Comment: "The board has unanimously resolved ..." :)

Comment: @Kris - "Board" is a collective noun. Cattle, like people, is not a collective noun. The people have spoken, not the people has spoken.

Comment: @David You didn't get the joke. :)

Answer (score 2):

Cattle is a plural noun that refers to more than one cow or bull. The collective noun that refers to a bunch of cattle as a group is "herd". The herd is moving, but  the cattle that comprise the herd are lowing.